# how to make httppost request

Tags: android, arrays, json, eclipse

I am new to android. i am learning http request for get, post,delete. from this i learned get and delete and also post request. 
But problem coment in sending array in post request.

This is my post data structure..

```
{
 "customerId": "CUST01",
 "orderId": "101010",
 "orderTotal": 99.99,
 "orderDetailList": [
  {
    "lineId": "1",
    "itemNumber": "ABC",
     "quantity": 9,
     "price": 10.0
   },
   {
     "lineId": "2",
     "itemNumber": "XYZ",
     "quantity": 1,
     "price": 9.99
   }
 ]
}
```

how to sent array in post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your request structure is JSONObject with the example data given above.

Now, Just create a JSONObject with the help of JSONObject class, here you can go through one of my presentation for [Web API & Its Integration in Android.](https://speakerdeck.com/pareshmayani/web-api-integration-in-android)

Example:

```
    JSONObject myJSONRequest = new JSONObject();
    myJSONRequest.put("customerId", "CUST01");
    myJSONRequest.put("orderId","101010");
    .........
    .........
    JSONArray arrayOrder = new JSONArray();
    for(int i=cntLine; i<n; i++)
    {
       JSONObject objSub = new JSONObject();
       objSub .put("lineId", String.valueOf(i));
       objSub .put("itemNumber", String.valueOf(i));
       .............
       .............

       arrayOrder.put(objSub);
    }
    myJSONRequest.put("orderDetailList", arrayOrder.toString());



    // create complete request object by placing all the values inside it.


    // Below code is for posting request data to web api

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    post.setEntity(new StringEntity(myJSONRequest.toString(), "utf-8"));
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

Comment: i wand to use jsonobject.put  or jsonarray.put

Comment: and the array    "orderDetailList": [
  {
    "lineId": "1",
    "itemNumber": "ABC",
     "quantity": 9,
     "price": 10.0
   },
   {
     "lineId": "2",
     "itemNumber": "XYZ",
     "quantity": 1,
     "price": 9.99
   }
 ]

Comment: can you please explain me how can i build an array in this format??

For e.g.
      "orderDetailList": [
  {
    "lineId": "1",
    "itemNumber": "ABC",
     "quantity": 9,
     "price": 10.0
   },
   {
     "lineId": "2",
     "itemNumber": "XYZ",
     "quantity": 1,
     "price": 9.99
   }
 ]

In this case how can i build an array?

Comment: @user2071490 For that you can use `JSONArray`, check updated code.

Comment: @user2071490 you should delete above comments so that it will look good and other user can found it useful. kindly upvote it also.

Answer (score 1):

Here i post some code to post value to the server..

```
       public void postData() {
      // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
       HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

      try {
// Add your data
//you can add all the parameters your php needs in the BasicNameValuePair. 
//The first parameter refers to the name in the php field for example
// $id=$_POST['customerId']; the second parameter is the value.
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("customerId", "CUST01"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("orderId", "101010"));
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("orderTotal", "99.99"));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

// Execute HTTP Post Request
 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

      } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      } catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  }}
```

Comment: jsonobject.put not NameValuePair that i know

Comment: check out this link also http://www.vogella.com/articles/ApacheHttpClient/article.html

Comment: @user2071490 A JSONObject is an unordered collection of name/value pairs. check this link http://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling6/org/apache/sling/commons/json/JSONObject.html

Answer (score 0):

Here I posted some code of How to get Content from url.

Now you have to pass String in Array.

```
try{


            HttpClient httpclient = getNewHttpClient();

            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("url");


            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }

        //convert response to string
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }
```

Comment: `HttpGet httppost`? Bad naming convention, plus OP wants to `POST` some data, and not `GET`.

Comment: OP wants to post data and here you have posted answer for fetching data.

Comment: this is a get method i had used it.

Answer (score 0):

In android its recommended that the developer uses HttpUrlConnection...

And You need the above json as string.

Step 1) Create new URL object.

```
URL url = new URL("www.url.com/demoservice");
```

Step 2) Create HttpURLConnection object.

```
HttpUrlConnection connection = url.openConnection();
```

Step 3) Set the request property to HttpPost..

```
connection.setRequestProperty("request-Method","POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("content-type","application/json");
```

Step 4) Get the output stream reference.

```
OutputStream stream = connection.getOutputStream();
```

Step 5) Write the json string to the output stream.

```
stream.write(jsonString.toBytes());
```

Step 6) Close the stream.

```
stream.close();
```

Hope this would be helpful..